# Will JsonContent get serialised multiple times using Json.NET in Web Api 2

Tags: asp.net, json, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

If I have this controller:

```
public class SomeController : ApiController
{
    public SomeInfoDto Get()
    {
        return new SomeInfoDto();
    }
}
```

When I call `/api/Some` with a get request I will get `JSON` in the Content Body because JSON.NET has been kind enough to serialise it for me.

However, if I wanted to send a `500` HTTP code and some `JSON` I thought I could do this:

```
public HttpResponseMessage Get()
{
    return new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError)
    {
        Content = // not sure what to put here
    }
}
```

So I googled to find out what to put for the `Content` and found this [resource](http://bizcoder.com/returning-raw-json-content-from-asp-net-web-api)

```
public class JsonContent : HttpContent
{
    private readonly JToken _value;

    public JsonContent(JToken value)
    {
        _value = value;
        Headers.ContentType = new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/json");
    }

    protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream,
        TransportContext context)
    {
        var jw = new JsonTextWriter(new StreamWriter(stream))
        {
            Formatting = Formatting.Indented
        };
        _value.WriteTo(jw);
        jw.Flush();
        return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
    }

    protected override bool TryComputeLength(out long length)
    {
        length = -1;
        return false;
    }
}
```

Which I can easily modify to fit my purposes.

**However, my question is, if I get `SerializeToStreamAsync` to use `JsonConvert.SerializeObject(_value)` further down the Web Api pipeline will it be serialised again?**

I have set the `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration` like this:

```
var formatters = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters;
var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
var settings = jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings;
settings.Formatting = Formatting.Indented;
settings.ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver();
```

My Implementation for the `SerializeToStreamAsync` is this:

```
protected override Task SerializeToStreamAsync(Stream stream, TransportContext context)
{
    using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(stream))
    {
        streamWriter.WriteAsync(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this.value)).Wait();
        streamWriter.FlushAsync().Wait();
    }

    return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Providing a concrete sample with formatter.
If you want to send JSON content with Http Status Code 500, you can use the extension method HttpRequestMessage.CreateResponse. There is no need for any advanced serialization and formatting. More info on that here.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httprequestmessageextensions.createresponse%28v=vs.118%29.aspx

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new string[] { "value1", "value2" }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())
```

(Or)

```
Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new string[] { "value1", "value2" }, 'application/json')
```

Comment: I used that in a raw fresh Web Api project and the output is serialized to xml, I'm guessing you have to set the MediaFormatter to JSON right?

Comment: If you could just add this example into your answer I will accept, only for answer completeness: `Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.InternalServerError, new string[] { "value1", "value2" }, new JsonMediaTypeFormatter())`

Comment: Instead of `new JsonMediaTypeFormatter()` you can use `GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters.JsonFormatter` if you want the globally configured one